# Use Escaped url in Django url regex mismatch

Tags: python, django, regex, django-rest-framework, escaping

I'm trying to use an escaped url as a `re_path` variable for an object identifier in my API. The logic to connect the escaped url to an object is there, but I can't figure out why the regex is not matching.

In my head, a `GET` request with the following url `/objects/http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A3030%2Fu%2F%3Fid%3Dc789793d-9538-4a27-9dd0-7bb487253da1/foo` should be parsed into `obj = 'http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A3030%2Fu%2F%3Fid%3Dc789793d-9538-4a27-9dd0-7bb487253da1'` and `field = 'foo'` for further processing. Ultimately, returning the object and `200`. However I am getting a `404` with a very specific Django error that only proliferates when Django unfruitfully iterates through all the paths available.

```
<HttpResponseNotFound status_code=404, "text/html">
(Pdb) response.content
b'\n<!doctype html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n  <title>Not Found</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n  <h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested resource was not found on this server.</p>\n</body>\n</html>\n'
```

I know the path exists as when I examine the `urlpatterns`, the path is present:

```
(Pdb) pp object_router.get_urls()
[
    ...
    <URLPattern '^(?P<obj>https?[-a-zA-Z0-9%._\+~#=]+)/(?P<field>foo|bar)\/?$' [name='test-detail-foobar']>
]
```

The url is escaped with `urllib.parse.quote(obj.url, safe="")`

Regexs tried:

- [r"https?[-a-zA-Z0-9%._+~#=]+"](https://regexr.com/6udq1)
- `r"https?[%23A](www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}(\.[a-z]{2,6})?\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)(?=\/foo)"` https://regexr.com/6ue7b
- [r"(https?://(www.)?)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%.*+~#=]{2,256}(.[a-z]{2,6})?\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%*+.~#?&//=]*)](https://regexr.com/6ue7e)

Edit:
Based off the Django Path Convertor `path` regex, I've changed my regex to `https?.+` with the compiled version as `'(?P<obj>https?.+)/(?P<field>foo|bar)\\/?$'`. This is moving in the right direction, however I've further identified some weirdness. Basically it seems that escaping the path variable url (`obj`) is partially to blame for the mismatch as an unescaped url (without query parameters) will return a differently handled API response. Further more, adding a query parameters/a question mark, once again returns us back to the Django 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a simple project like this:

urls.py

```python
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"https?[-a-zA-Z0-9%._+~#=]+", views.test, name="test"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

views.py

```python
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request, obj, field):
    print(f"The object is {obj}")
    print(f"The field is {field}")
    return HttpResponse("Test test")
```

When visiting the following URL: `/objects/http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A3030%2Fu%2F%3Fid%3Dc789793d-9538-4a27-9dd0-7bb487253da1/foo`

You get this error:

[image: URL error page]
(I've outlined the relevant part with red.)

Django automatically decodes the encoded URL and only then applies the regex match. `objects/http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A3030%2Fu%2F%3Fid%3Dc789793d-9538-4a27-9dd0-7bb487253da1/foo` becomes `objects/http://0.0.0.0:3030/u/?id=c789793d-9538-4a27-9dd0-7bb487253da1/foo`. You will have to write the equivalent regex expression that matches against the decoded URL.

Something like this will work:

urls.py

```python
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"(?P<obj>https?:\/\/.*\?id=[\d\w-]+)\/(?P<field>foo|bar)", views.test, name="test"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

views.py

```python
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request, obj, field):
    print(f"The object is {obj}")
    print(f"The field is {field}")
    return HttpResponse("Test test")
```

Visiting the URL `/objects/http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A3030%2Fu%2F%3Fid%3Dc789793d-9538-4a27-9dd0-7bb487253da1/foo` will print the following to the console:

```plaintext
The object is http://0.0.0.0:3030/u/?id=c789793d-9538-4a27-9dd0-7bb487253da1 
The field is foo
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this or is just speculative? Modified my regex (regular string, not `r`) to as follows `(?P<foo>https?:\\/\\/.*\\?([^=&\\s]+=[^=&\\s]+&?)+)\\/(?P<field>foo|bar)` which [works](https://regexr.com/6uu0u), but I'm still getting the unfound 404

Comment: Yep, tried this and it should work.

Comment: Create a new project with my code and try the original URL. It should work.

Comment: This works and is accurate. I'm still having issues, but they have to be outside of Django

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your issue properly, it looks like you are attempting to get a regex match and immediately send a request to the resultant url?

If that is the case, you are sending the request to an improperly formatted url. The first regex you posted looks like it works just fine to get the result you are asking for, however it results in a url that is [still encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP).

You need to "unquote" the url prior to making the request.

```
import re
from urllib.parse import unquote

path = '/objects/http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A3030%2Fu%2F%3Fid%3Dc789793d-9538-4a27-9dd0-7bb487253da1/foo'

resp = re.search("https?[-a-zA-Z0-9%._+~#=]+", path)
url = resp[0]
print(url)
print(unquote(url))
```

results in and output of:

```
http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A3030%2Fu%2F%3Fid%3Dc789793d-9538-4a27-9dd0-7bb487253da1

http://0.0.0.0:3030/u/?id=c789793d-9538-4a27-9dd0-7bb487253da1
```

Comment: Not send a request, id an object; objects in my API are identified by their pk or their url. One should be able to `GET` an object via that attribute as long as you specify `foo` or `bar` post. The issue isn't decoding the URL afterwards, rather that when passing an object's url as an url variable (escaped), the regex can't match on it. Strangely enough, the regex `.+` from [Django's path converter's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) is the only regex to work so far